# Built-in scheduler functionality in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks

My MVC3 application is using an SQL Server 2008 to store data. In particular - support ticket management data.

I have a table in a database - Tickets.

I are reviewing a possibility of implementing a recurring ticket registration, using an SQL Server features.

Is there a built-in SQL Server functionality, that would allow me to schedule, a, for example, once a week creation of a row in a database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) and run a [Transact-SQL Job Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx).

Note that the agent runs as a service under a particular account, which will need rights to be able to carry out whatever operations your need.

Comment: Unfortunately, the SQL Agent will not work if your using the Express version of SQL Server. Too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you haven't mentioned your SQL Server Edition. If you have Express then there is no built-in scheduler so you need to use the Windows scheduler to run a batch file or other program that connects to SQL Server.

If you have any other edition, then you have SQL Agent which is a full scheduler with support for just about any task including running SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the Windows SchedTask Control Panel to schedule a batch file to run periodically:

In the batch file create a SQL string like so:

```
SET SQLSTRING=INSERT INTO Persons^
 VALUES (4,'Nilsen', 'Johan', 'Bakken 2',^
 'Stavanger');
```

Then, just enable delayed expansion and use something like this:

```
sqlcmd.exe -b -S localhost -E -d !DBNAME! -Q "!SQLSTRING!" -W
```